# How to return year events in a for loop from an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, input

Advanced – For Loops

Create a program that takes someone’s age, and then outputs a key event from every year they have lived through.

· Extension, allow a user to input their birthday for further accuracy

· Code efficiency, use an array for key events instead of if statements.

I have created the array consisting of years and events from 1993

So how do I create a for loop which gets a users year of birth (input) and displays the events from that year to the current year?

```
edYearlyEvents = {                                                                                                                                                                      
"1993": "Bill Clinton is inaugurated as the 42nd president.",                                                                                                                      
"1994": "The People's Republic of China gets its first connection to the Internet.",                                                                                               
"1995": "eBay is founded by Pierre Omidyar.",                                                                                                                                      
"1996": "Murder of Tupac Shakur.",                                                                                                                                                 
"1997": "The first episode of Pokémon airs on TV Tokyo.",                                                                                                                          
"1998": "Death of Frank Sinatra.",                                                                                                                                                 
"1999": "The Columbine High School massacre in Colorado, United States, causes 15 deaths.",                                                                                        
"2000": "The Sony PlayStation 2 releases in Japan. ",                                                                                                                              
"2001": " September 11 attacks.",                                                                                                                                                  
"2002": "The 2002-2004 SARS outbreak began in Guangdong.",                                                                                                                         
"2003": "The United States invades Iraq and ousts Saddam Hussein, triggering worldwide protests and an 8 year war",                                                                
"2004": "First surface images of Saturn's moon Titan.",                                                                                                                            
"2005": "Hurricane Katrina kills 1,836 people in the Gulf of Mexico.",                                                                                                             
"2006": "Twitter is launched.",                                                                                                                                                    
"2007": "Introduction of the iPhone.",                                                                                                                                             
"2008": "Barack Obama is elected to become the first black President of the United States.",                                                                                       
"2009": "The cryptocurrency Bitcoin is launched.",                                                                                                                                 
"2010": "The Burj Khalifa in Dubai becomes the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft).",                                                                   
"2011": "Osama bin Laden is shot dead by United States Navy SEALs in Pakistan.",                                                                                                   
"2012": "Vladimir Putin is elected president of Russia for the third time.",                                                                                                       
"2013": "Terrorist attacks occur in Boston and Nairobi.",                                                                                                                          
"2014": "The worst Ebola epidemic in recorded history occurs in West Africa, infecting nearly 30,000 people and resulting in the deaths of 11,000+.",                              
"2015": "Liquid water is found on Mars.",                                                                                                                                          
"2016": "El Chapo is recaptured following his escape from a high-security prison in Mexico",                                                                                       
"2017": "January 20: Donald Trump is inaugurated as President of the United States.",                                                                                              
"2018": "Saudi Arabia allows women to drive.",                                                                                                                                     
"2019": "A major fire engulfs Notre-Dame Cathedral in Paris, resulting in the roof and main spire collapsing.",                                                                    
"2020": "The murder of George Floyd sparks protests across the United States and the world.",                                                                                      
"2021": "Supporters of President Donald Trump, gathered after a rally led by him, attack the United States capitol, leading to five deaths.",                                      
"2022": "Monkeypox outbreak",                                                                                                                                                      
"2023": "The funeral of Pope Benedict XVI is held at Saint Peter's Square within the Vatican City.",
```

}

sBirthYear = input("What year were you born in: \n")

for sBirthYear in dYearlyEvents.items():
print(sBirthYear)

Comment: Could you drop some part of your code so we can take a look.

Comment: I did but it messed up the format, basically need a for loop that when a year is entered by the user is only returns the years from that date till 2023 if that makes sense?

Comment: try to use editor's toolbar, icon with a curly braces `{}` to insert your code snippet. This will help the community to help you in solving your problem.

Comment: Example:
I born in 1995 
return value should be `["1993: "...","1994": "..."]`  right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const events = {                   
"1993": "Bill Clinton is inaugurated as the 42nd president.",                                                                                                                      
"1994": "The People's Republic of China gets its first connection to the Internet.",                                                                                               
"1995": "eBay is founded by Pierre Omidyar.",                                                                                                                                      
"1996": "Murder of Tupac Shakur.",                                                                                                                                                 
"1997": "The first episode of Pokémon airs on TV Tokyo.",                                                                                                                          
"1998": "Death of Frank Sinatra.",                                                                                                                                                 
"1999": "The Columbine High School massacre in Colorado, United States, causes 15 deaths.",                                                                                        
"2000": "The Sony PlayStation 2 releases in Japan. ",                                                                                                                              
"2001": " September 11 attacks.",                                                                                                                                                  
"2002": "The 2002-2004 SARS outbreak began in Guangdong.",                                                                                                                         
"2003": "The United States invades Iraq and ousts Saddam Hussein, triggering worldwide protests and an 8 year war",                                                                
"2004": "First surface images of Saturn's moon Titan.",                                                                                                                            
"2005": "Hurricane Katrina kills 1,836 people in the Gulf of Mexico.",                                                                                                             
"2006": "Twitter is launched.",                                                                                                                                                    
"2007": "Introduction of the iPhone.",                                                                                                                                             
"2008": "Barack Obama is elected to become the first black President of the United States.",                                                                                       
"2009": "The cryptocurrency Bitcoin is launched.",                                                                                                                                 
"2010": "The Burj Khalifa in Dubai becomes the tallest structure in the world, standing at 829.8 m (2,722 ft).",                                                                   
"2011": "Osama bin Laden is shot dead by United States Navy SEALs in Pakistan.",                                                                                                   
"2012": "Vladimir Putin is elected president of Russia for the third time.",                                                                                                       
"2013": "Terrorist attacks occur in Boston and Nairobi.",                                                                                                                          
"2014": "The worst Ebola epidemic in recorded history occurs in West Africa, infecting nearly 30,000 people and resulting in the deaths of 11,000+.",                              
"2015": "Liquid water is found on Mars.",                                                                                                                                          
"2016": "El Chapo is recaptured following his escape from a high-security prison in Mexico",                                                                                       
"2017": "January 20: Donald Trump is inaugurated as President of the United States.",                                                                                              
"2018": "Saudi Arabia allows women to drive.",                                                                                                                                     
"2019": "A major fire engulfs Notre-Dame Cathedral in Paris, resulting in the roof and main spire collapsing.",                                                                    
"2020": "The murder of George Floyd sparks protests across the United States and the world.",                                                                                      
"2021": "Supporters of President Donald Trump, gathered after a rally led by him, attack the United States capitol, leading to five deaths.",                                      
"2022": "Monkeypox outbreak",                                                                                                                                                      
"2023": "The funeral of Pope Benedict XVI is held at Saint Peter's Square within the Vatican City.",
}

const yearOfBirth = 1995

const eventsBeforeMyBirth = Object.keys(events).filter(i => Number(i) <= yearOfBirth).map(i => {
  return {
    [i]: events[i]
  }
})

console.log(eventsBeforeMyBirth)
```